# How to validate json schema against metaschema in linux cli

Tags: json, command-line-interface, jsonschema, python-jsonschema

I'm trying to validate my complex **json schema** definition file to be sure that there is no typo in the schema.
I use the `jsonschema` script provided by [python jsonschema library](https://pypi.org/project/jsonschema/).

I use meta-schema files downloaded from [json schema specification page](https://json-schema.org/specification.html).

I was downloaded the "Core/Validation Dialect meta-schema" file and all "Single-vocabulary meta-schemas", added the "json" extension and store these files in this structure:

```
├── meta
│   ├── applicator.json
│   ├── content.json
│   ├── core.json
│   ├── format-annotation.json
│   ├── format-assertion.json
│   ├── meta-data.json
│   ├── unevaluated.json
│   └── validation.json
└── schema.json
```

If I create this `test01.json` file (notice the "objectx" typo on line 5):

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "$id": "https://example.com/sample/conf.schema.json",
  "title": "Sample",
  "type": "objectx",
  "properties": {
    "browser": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "foo": {
          "type": "string"
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

then the validation fail (as expected):

```
$ jsonschema -i test01.json some/path/schema.json
objectx: 'objectx' is not valid under any of the given schemas
```

But when I make similar typo in embedded object (see line 8) in `test02.json`:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "$id": "https://example.com/sample/conf.schema.json",
  "title": "Sample",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "browser": {
      "type": "objectx",
      "properties": {
        "foo": {
          "type": "string"
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

then the validation pass (no output is printed):

```
$ jsonschema -i test02.json some/path/schema.json
```

How can I validate complex json schema document (not only the top level object) from CLI in linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CLI in [jsonschema](https://pypi.org/project/jsonschema/) is deprecated in these days.

It is recommended to use [check-jsonschema](https://pypi.org/project/check-jsonschema/) instead.
It has a `--check-metaschema` option. This means that it has embedded meta schema files, so there is no need to download meta schema manually anymore. That's good news.

The second good news is, that **it just works and it is able to validate complex schema** documents:

```bash
$ check-jsonschema --check-metaschema test02.json 
Schema validation errors were encountered.
  test02.json::$.properties.browser.type: 'objectx' is not valid under any of the given schemas
  Underlying errors caused this.
  Best Match:
    $.properties.browser.type: 'objectx' is not one of ['array', 'boolean', 'integer', 'null', 'number', 'object', 'string']
```